# Best way to Write a Table of Contents for Awkward Pagination

Tags: journalism, pages, notes, table-of-contents

I have a piccadilly journal that I use for taking notes on self-taught subjects and I have an awkward structure for pagination and page structure:

[image: Sample Page]

Page numbers only exist on the right hand side of the page and I read the **journal** from left to right; however, I read **journal entries** from right to left (in pages, not words). When a journal entry only spans a single page, I write a new entry on the left side of the journal with the respective date and title on the bottom but I never write new page numbers on the left page.

The journal is now ~56 pages (112 physical pages) and it's becoming difficult to find entries now. I want to list all of the entries in the back as a table of contents or index of some sort but I want to be as space-efficient as possible; how should I do this to be least-redundant (least repetition of page numbers or dates)?

P.S. If I sort them traditionally by pages, some pages will have two entries and others will only have one entry that spans two pages (asymmetrical). If I sort by date, I may have multiple entries per date that spans multiple pages (since I can write more than one journal entry in a day).

Comment: WTF? Are you kidding us? Add page numbers to the left pages (1b, 2b, 3b, ...) and happy indexing.

Comment: @John, must also include dates

Answer (score 4):

If you want to look up by both title and date, I'd list each entry as:

> [Entry title] [Entry date] [Page Number]

where "Page Number" refers to your existing 2-page numbering. You'll have no trouble finding the entry you're looking for once you've opened up the right 2 pages...

Comment: Yes, and in future, stop numbering the pages that way.

Answer (score 0):

You could arbitrarily re-number the pages. Use a prefix like A, start at the lower outside corner of the first page, and call it A1. Your next page, left or right, is A2. Continue to the end. Use that for your TOC/Index.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just make your TOC refer to the page numbers as they are? So "Heuristics ... 14" would take you to this page. Whether you read the right page or the left page first, presumably you know your system.

If you are planning to publish this for others to read, I'd switch it to a more normal ordering and page numbering. It's not at all clear what is gained by the funny page numbering and right/left rules.